# Access a property of a class from another class objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have gone through many questions in here but is still unable to find a solution to my problem. I have a class named `ModelClass` and another class named `ViewController` and yet another called `ViewController2`. I have the following properties in `ModelClass`:

```
@property (assign) int DataFromVC1;
@property (assign) int DataFromVC2;
```

I have the data collected from VC1 and VC2 and I correctly displayed the required data using NSLog from the corresponding view controllers. But when I try to send `DataFromVC1` to VC2, and use NSLog to display 'DataFromVC1' from within VC2, it is showing `0`. But it is displaying the correct value when NSLog is called from VC1.

I used the following code segments to import the MainClass in the ViewController class implementations(just including the relevant parts):

```
#import "ModelClass.h"
@interface ViewController2 ()
{    
    ModelClass *MC;    
}
@implementation ViewController
....
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    .....
    MC = [[ModelClass alloc]init];
}
<function that gets the data>
{
    .....
    NSLog(@"%d",MC.DataFromVC1);
    ....
}
<function that sets the data>
{
    .....
    MC.DataFromVC2 = requiredData;
    .....
}
```

And similar code in the other ViewController class as well. Why is the data set to zero while sending from one class to another? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't understand all you have written, but if you want to make some interaction with few controllers in iOS I suggest you using `NSNotification`s. I find your code not very object-oriented.

Comment: Simply speaking, I need to set a value to property called DataFromVC1 declared in ModelClass from ViewController and access the value from ViewController2 but I can't.

Comment: Are you sure that the two view controllers hold the same instance of `ModelClass`?

Comment: If yes, the best practice is using singleton

Comment: this sounds like a problem about passing data between view controllers more than anything else, take a look [at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers) it is very detailed and if it doesnt help, then as Valentin said in the comments, maybe a singleton solution will help you.

Comment: I tried with singleton but yet the same result. Yes, the two view controllers must use the same instance of ModelClass. How can I do it with Singleton? I tried `http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/` but it didn't work